# How to get a Mandrill API key?

Tags: email, mandrill

I just signed up with MandrillApp to send emails via code, and they speak of an API key that must be used to send emails or use the API. However, I could not find any mention of how/where to get an API key.

Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was related to screen resolution, and their webpage design.

I eventually noticed some image on the SMTP settings page, and tried to scroll down (If I recall correctly there was no scroll bar visible), and there, lo and behold to my great suprise was a "Create New Key" button.

Comment: where is smtp settings page ?

Comment: since MandrillApp changed their pricing policy (i.e. to no longer be free), I moved on to something else

Comment: I find answer. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 4):

you can generate it from admin panel /Account/ Extra/ API Keys/ Create a Mandrill api key . then you need to active your plan from Transactional
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To create a test API key:

1. Go to **Settings** in your Mandrill account.
2. Click **+ New API Key**.
3. Enter a description of the key.
4. Click Create API Key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be referring to the Mandrill Docs:

Getting Started: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/200277237

Getting your Access Information aka API Key: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582397-How-do-I-access-Mandrill-for-sending-email-

HTTP API: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/

Comment: As far as I could see, none of these links actually describe how to get an API key.

Comment: metoo, i can not get api key from account